# How to adapt the string `reprintof' in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think there is small bug in some styles of biblatex. I want to print a reference to a reprint which I can achieve with the following MWE. But: with some styles I'm getting a dot after 'Repr. of.' which is obviously false. In `english.lbx` the bibstring `reprintof` is defined as `{{reprint of}{repr\adddotspace of}}`. That means the dot is coming from some `\newunit` maybe, but I can not figure out how the refernece is built by biblatex.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{stack2.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{ubeda04:_libro_justinreprint}.
\end{document}
```

And the bib file:

```
@Book{ubeda04:_libro_justinreprint,
 author =       {Úbeda, Francisco de},
 title =        {Libro de entretenimiento de la pícara Justina},
 year =         2004,
 publisher =    {Simancas Ediciones},
 related =      {ubeda04:_libro_justin},
 relatedtype =  {reprintof}
 }

@Book{ubeda04:_libro_justin,
 author =       {Úbeda, Francisco de},
 title =        {Libro de entretenimiento de la pícara Justina},
 year =         1604,
 location =     {Madrid},
 }
```

How could I change this and suppress the dot?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a bug for any but the `authoryear` style family. A quick workaround is

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{reprintof = {repr\adddotspace of\nopunct}}
```

but the underlying cause is probably a superfluous `\newunit\newpunct` somewhere that should be removed by the `biblatex` maintainers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{reprintof = {repr\adddotspace of\nopunct}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{ubeda04:_libro_justinreprint,
 author =       {Úbeda, Francisco de},
 title =        {Libro de entretenimiento de la pícara Justina},
 year =         2004,
 publisher =    {Simancas Ediciones},
 related =      {ubeda04:_libro_justin},
 relatedtype =  {reprintof}
 }
@Book{ubeda04:_libro_justin,
 author =       {Úbeda, Francisco de},
 title =        {Libro de entretenimiento de la pícara Justina},
 year =         1604,
 location =     {Madrid},
 }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{ubeda04:_libro_justinreprint}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can someone open a bug on github for this with a MWE?

Comment: @PLK: I could do it my self, because I have also an account on github, but I have no expierence with opening bugs. Should I put the MWE inside the comment itself or somehow outside?

Comment: @lockstep: thanks. It is of course working with this solution.

Comment: You can just include it in the initial comment - just wrap it in a quote block (three backticks on a line alone to start and end the block - you can also put "latex" after the first three opening backticks line and it will highlight tex code).

Comment: @lockstep: could you maybe let me know how you create the jpg image? Simply creating a pdf->jpg and then manipulating the image or is there another `magic' way? Thanks in advance

Comment: @rogorido In a rather crude way -- captured screenshot of PDF, pasted it into IrfanView, cropped it by hand, uploaded it.